# How to suppress C26454 code analysis pulled in from CommCtrl.h?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I've implemented a virtual List View control. To do so, I need to handle the [LVN_GETDISPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo) notification. I've done it like I've always done it in the past:

```cpp
    case WM_NOTIFY: {
        auto const& nmhdr { *reinterpret_cast<NMHDR const*>(lParam) };
        if (nmhdr.idFrom == IDC_MY_LIST_VIEW && nmhdr.code == LVN_GETDISPINFOW)
        {
            // ...
```

The only thing that changed is that I'm using Visual Studio 2019 now. And the document health indicator doesn't like how `LVN_GETDISPINFOW` is defined. It's a preprocessor macro `(LVN_FIRST-77)` with `LVN_FIRST` being `(0U-100U)`. That triggers [C26454](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c26454):

> Arithmetic overflow: '%operator%' operation produces a negative unsigned result at compile time

The warning is greatly appreciated, just not when it comes out of header files I do not control. I can disable the warning by wrapping the affected code inside a `pragma warning(disable:26454)` directive (properly restoring the previous state right after it). This being a macro, however, I need to do this in *my* code, *everywhere* I use any of those constants.

That works, sure. But it's tedious. Is there a way to suppress this warning for all constants defined in `CommCtrl.h`, without affecting the check for other code?

Comment: Use pragma warning default to restore it.

Comment: @mic: I'm well aware of how to restore the previous state, by wrapping this inside a `pragma warning(push)`/`pragma warning(pop)` (**not** `pragma warning(default:26454)`!). I just don't want to spray this across all of my code that happens to use a constant defined elsewhere, in a less than ideal way.

Comment: The only way I've managed (comes a lot in `MESSAGE_MAP` declarations) is to use the `#pragma warning(suppress:26454)` line (disables the warning **just for the next line**). Still tedious, but *slightly* less so than 'push … pop' (two lines) each time.

Comment: Use Analyze > Configure Code Analysis

Comment: @HansPassant: And then what next? Configure what? Where's that magic setting, that allows me to only target constants defined in a system header? Is it maybe hidden behind the only entry on that dialog that reads: *"NOTE: This property page has been deprecated and will be removed in a future product release."*?

Comment: @adr: That's better already. Not quite what I was looking for, but better already.

Comment: As `LVN_GETDISPINO` is a macro that is only evaluated when used (i.e. outside of the system header where it's #defined), I can't see a way of telling the code analyser to ignore 'stuff from system headers' in such cases. Though I would **not** specifically recommend this, you *could* just have `#undef LVN_GETDISPINO` and `#define LVN_GETDISPINO 0x12345678` (or whatever it actually is) in your 'top' header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves this issue for me with VS2019. You can have a try:

```
case WM_NOTIFY: {
    auto const& nmhdr{ *reinterpret_cast<NMHDR const*>(lParam) };
    switch (nmhdr.code)
    {
    case LVN_GETDISPINFOW:
        if (nmhdr.idFrom == IDC_MY_LIST_VIEW)
        {
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Refer to "[LVN_GETDISPINFO notification code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo)".

Comment: Oddly enough, when placed in a `switch`/`case`, the constant no longer triggers a code analysis diagnostic. What's unfortunate about this is, that the only thing I don't need in a `WM_NOTIFY`-handler is yet another nested level of `switch`/`case`s. My overall intent was to improve readability of my code. While this doesn't help much, it still answers the question that was asked.